# Proof that analytic function whose absolute value tends to infinity in all directions takes on all complex values

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove that if $f$ is analytic and $$ |f(z)| \to \infty$$ as $|z|\to\infty$, then $f$ must necessarily take on any complex value for some $z$. Here is my proof, which I believe is correct but want to leave for others to scrutinize: Suppose $f$ does not take on the complex value $a$, we prove the result to be true by contradiction. Then, the function $$g(z)=\frac{1}{z(f(z)-a)}$$ is meromorphic and has a pole only at $z=0$ since the equation $f(z)=a$ has no solutions by our assumption. Hence, by Cauchy's residue theorem, a contour around 0 should evaluate to $$\frac{2\pi i}{f(0)-a}$$ However, a parametrization via $z=re^{i \theta}$ and taking the limit as $r \to \infty$ yields:  $$ \lim_{r \to \infty}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{re^{i\theta}id\theta}{re^{i\theta}(f(re^{i\theta})-a)} = \lim_{r \to \infty}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{i}{(f(re^{i\theta})-a)} = 0 $$ Since $0 \neq \frac{2\pi i}{f(0)-a}$ we have a contradiction and the proof is complete.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your proof is completely good! Here is another one:

If $f(z)$ never equals $a$, consider the function $g(z)=1/(f(z)-a)$. This is the reciprocal of a nonvanishing entire function, hence itself entire. But $|g(z)|\to0$ as $|z|\to\infty$, which implies that $g(z)$ is bounded. Hence $g(z)$ must be constant, which leads quickly to a contradiction.

Comment: yes, ironically I thought of this once I had written the other... this one is simpler, taking Louiville's theorem for granted of course

Comment: Of course - and the proof of Liouville is somewhat similar to your proof!

Answer (score 2):

The function would have a pole at infinity (and not an essential singularity), which means it's a polynomial. The result would then follow from the fundamental theorem of algebra.